# jQuery - Simple math returning NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do some simple math, using below function. The function is called `onChange`:

```
var exposure = $('#exposure').find(":selected").val();
var budget = $('.budget').val();
var ppc = $('.ppc').val();
var value = budget/ppc;
var total2 = Math.floor(value*0.95);

if(exposure == 2){
    var dref = 0.0005;
}else if(exposure == 3){
    var dref = 0.005;
}else if(exposure == 4){
    var dref = 0.001;       
}

if(exposure > 1){
    var add = dref+ppc;
    var value2 = budget/add;
    var total2 = Math.floor(value2*0.95);
}
$("#sum").text("" + total2 + " Clicks");
```

My problem is, that if `exposure > 1`, the `total2` value in `#sum` will return `NaN`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What possible values can `exposure` have? If it is anything other than 2, 3 or 4 your `dref` variable won't be assigned a value, so then `add` will be `Nan` so then `value2` will be `NaN`, so then `total2` will be `NaN`.

Comment: Only 1,2,3 or 4. I have tried to do a console.log(exposure), and the value is correct.

Comment: What are the values of `exposure`, `budget`, and `ppc`?

Comment: @Xymostech Exposure = 2, budget = 5, ppc = 0.005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `parseInt(value,10)` for intergers or `parseFloat(value)` for float.

JavaScript appends the values if the data type is not a number.

Like:

```
budget = parseInt(budget,10);
```

Comment: To where should I add this in my code? Around the math calculations or?

Answer (score 0):

You got to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`. I would say `parseFloat` something like,

```
var budget = parseFloat($('.budget').val());
var ppc = parseFloat($('.ppc').val());
var value = parseFloat(budget/ppc);
var total2 = parseFloat((value*0.95));
```